# Database information not lining up in a table (php/sql)

Tags: php, css, mysql

When using CSS for my DetailsTable the information I am getting from the database is not being displayed correctly in the table. All of that information is getting bunched up together and therefore isn't being laid out as a table.

If anyone could suggest why the information I am trying to get isn't being laid out in a table form that would be much appreciated

```
</head>
<body>
 <div id="DetailsTable" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>TypeOfShoe</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price(£)</th>
            <th>Fabric</th>
            <th>Colour</th>
            <th>Brand</th>

        </tr>  
    </table>
    <?php
    $shoesID=$_GET['id'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT shoes.name, shoes.images, shoes.description, shoes.price, types.typeOfShoe, types.fabric, types.colour, brands.name AS bname FROM shoes INNER JOIN types on types.types_id = shoes.type_id INNER JOIN brands on brands.brands_id = shoes.brands_id
    WHERE shoes.id = :id"); 

    $stmt->bindValue(':id',$shoesID);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($shoes=$stmt->fetch()){
        echo "<td>".$shoes['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$shoes['typeOfShoe']."</td>";  
        echo "<td>".$shoes['description']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$shoes['price']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$shoes['fabric']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$shoes['colour']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$shoes['bname']."</td>";
    }  

    $conn=NULL;
    ?>
    <br> <br/>
    <div id="Image" >
        <img src="<?php echo $shoes['images']; ?>" height="500px" width="500px" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code is below.

```
body {
background-color: lemonchiffon;
 }        

#DetailsTable {

border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
 }

th, td {
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
 }



#Image{
display: block;
margin: auto;
width: 50%;
height: 10px;
clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have closed the`</table`> tag before the php code, that maybe the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
    </head>
<body>
 <div id="DetailsTable" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>TypeOfShoe</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price(£)</th>
            <th>Fabric</th>
            <th>Colour</th>
            <th>Brand</th>

        </tr>  
    <?php
    $shoesID=$_GET['id'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT shoes.name, shoes.images, shoes.description, shoes.price, types.typeOfShoe, types.fabric, types.colour, brands.name AS bname FROM shoes INNER JOIN types on types.types_id = shoes.type_id INNER JOIN brands on brands.brands_id = shoes.brands_id
    WHERE shoes.id = :id"); 

    $stmt->bindValue(':id',$shoesID);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($shoes=$stmt->fetch()){
    echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>".$shoes['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$shoes['typeOfShoe']."</td>";  
        echo "<td>".$shoes['description']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$shoes['price']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$shoes['fabric']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$shoes['colour']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$shoes['bname']."</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
    }  

    $conn=NULL;
    ?>
    </html>
    <br> <br/>
    <div id="Image" >
        <img src="<?php echo $shoes['images']; ?>" height="500px" width="500px" />
    </div>
</div>
```